# Excel Add-In throws SHException

Tags: c#, excel-addins, excel-dna, ribbonx

I have an excel addin, written in C#, .NET 35 SP1
using ExcelDNA, NetOffice 
Occasionally clients reported my add-in disappear from Excel, I check it is in disabled addin list, 
I enable it and it works again. 
I checked my log and saw SHException. Not sure what causes and how to fix it.  thanks

One thing I notice client has several other addins in Excel.  Also has .NET 1.1, .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0, NET 35 SP1

```
2012-01-31 07:10:12,672 [1] ERROR Shared.Helper [(null)] - Name:SEHException
Message:External component has thrown an exception.
Target:Int32 IntGetMessageW(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32)
Stack:   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntGetMessageW(MSG& msg, HandleRef hWnd, Int32 uMsgFilterMin, Int32 uMsgFilterMax)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMessageW(MSG& msg, HandleRef hWnd, Int32 uMsgFilterMin, Int32 uMsgFilterMax)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.GetMessage(MSG& msg, IntPtr hwnd, Int32 minMessage, Int32 maxMessage)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at ExcelAddIn.Connect.ShowRefreshUI(Boolean checkForSettings, Boolean isRefreshAll)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks, Josh Christie. Found solution @ http://www.joshchristie.com/weblog/archives/2003_09.html

Call DoEvents after EnableVisualStyles
This bug in the 1.1 version of the .NET framework can, fortunately, be solved by calling Application.DoEvents() right after calling Application.EnableVisualStyles(). That's it, problem solved. :)

and Scott Hanselman
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnableVisualStylesStrikesAgain.aspx